Embedding between Sobolev spaces.
I have a question about embeddings of the Sobolev space. I am not sure if the inclusion mentioned (in the question) is true. I attach some context
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set. Let $H^{r,p}(\Omega)=\left\{u\in L^p(\Omega)\colon \left\|u\right\|_{H^{r,p}(\Omega)}=\left\|\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^2)^{r/2}\widehat{u}\right)\right\|_{L^p(\Omega)}<\infty\right\}$ (Bessel potential space)
Theorem. $1<p<\infty,\, -\infty<s_1\leq s_2$, then
\begin{align}
H^{s_2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset H^{s_1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{align}
(This theorem is a particular case of the theorem (b) page 203 in  H. Triebel, Interpolation Theory, Function Spaces, Differential Operators (North-Holland Pub. Co, Amsterdam ; New York, 1978) because the Triebel-Lizorkin space $F_{p,2}^{r}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is $H^{r,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$)
Question. Is the embedding also valid over an open set $\Omega$?, i.e, $H^{s_2,p}(\Omega)\subset H^{s_1,p}(\Omega)$?
Thanks.

The definition is already invalid: how do you define Fourier transform for functions defined only on domain?
